# How do I use a button in Another Method?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a text adventure after a choice is submitted i want it to move to the next method and allow you to press submit again. How would I do this?

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    if (option1.isSelected()) {
        one(); 
    } else if (option2.isSelected()) {
        two();            
    } else {

    }
}                                      

private void one() {
    //Button action here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-align your thinking. It's not the next *method* that you want to call but rather the next ***state*** -- you want to change the *state* of your model (the logical portion of your program) depending on where the user is and what responses he makes, and change the behavior of the program to the user's responses based on this *state*. What you don't want to do is to to hard-wire your code as you're currently doing as this will lead to rigid programs, programs that cannot adapt to changes in user selection or changes to the logic of the program itself.

Again, the best solution to your general problem is to gear your program to use the [state design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) where the response of the program to input depends on the *state* of the model (the object that controls what happens).

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: @GerryStraatsma: you're looking for a simple single code solution, and it doesn't exist. Instead the solution is to learn java and programming on a deeper level and learn to separate your code from your data, your logic from your user-interaction.

Comment: @GerryStraatsma: otherwise for better answers to questions, post more pertinent information about your code and your problem, including a [mcve] and much more pertinent background information. Your question right now is very broad, very general, and so the only decent solutions will by necessity also be very broad and general.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the same button will be used in the progression of your adventure. If that's the case, you could start by registering a first `ActionListener` whose `actionPerformed()` corresponds to one. at the end of that method, you can `deregister` the listener and register a new one whose `actionPerformed` implementation is `two()`

Comment: how would this look like in my code?

Comment: @GerryStraatsma: you're barking up the wrong tree and are heading towards little but frustration if you follow this path and continue with hard-coded rigid code.